# What could be in my xml causing this stackoverflow?

Tags: java, xml

I'm validating an xml against a known schema and getting a stackoverflow error. What is wrong with my xml? What should I be looking for? That error is thrown from code found in 1.6 Java.

```
JAXBContext context = JAXBContext.newInstance(Root.class);
        Unmarshaller un = context.createUnmarshaller();
        SchemaFactory schemaFactory = SchemaFactory.newInstance(XMLConstants.W3C_XML_SCHEMA_NS_URI);
        URL resource = ClassLoader.getSystemResource("schema.xsd");
        if (resource == null) {
            throw new IllegalStateException("Could not find schema!");
        }
        Schema schema = schemaFactory.newSchema(resource);
        un.setSchema(schema);
        Root root = un.unmarshal(xml) // Error thrown here
```

Error:

```
    java.lang.StackOverflowError
        at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.xpath.regex.RegularExpression.matchString(RegularExpression.java:1878)
        at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.xpath.regex.RegularExpression.matchString(RegularExpression.java:1878)
```

Comment: What does the XML look like?

Comment: What does the XSD look like?